# CakePHPでSet::mergeを使ってcssファイルを統合する

Tags: php, cakephp

業務であるアプリケーションの`app/View/Layouts`にあるソースコードをみていると以下のようにしてcssファイルを一つにまとめていました。

```
<?php
$css_files = array(
    CSS . 'bootstrap.less',
    CSS . 'jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css',
    CSS . 'fullcalendar.css',
    CSS . 'jssocials.css',
    CSS . 'font-awesome.css',
    CSS . 'jssocials-theme-classic.css',

);
$css_files = Set::merge($css_files, Configure::read('site.default.css_files'));
?>
```

この場合、どのタイミングでこれらのファイルが一纏めになるのでしょうか？
今後変更する可能性がある場合の時のために知りたいと思っております。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set::merge`は、`array_merge`のように配列を組み合わせるためのメソッドです。

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::merge

CSSを結合する機能はありません。

Comment: ちなみにCSSの結合が可能なCakePHPプラグインとして https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress があります。（あらかじめSassやLESSで結合してしまうのが一般的でしょうが。

Comment: ありがとうございました。まだイマイチMerge::の使い方をしっかりと把握できていませんが、やはりSass, Lessが一般的なのですね。